# embed vs flash video player for displaying video

Tags: html, video

I want to show video in one of my pages of an enterprise application. I was thinking on using a flash based player such as [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/). Then I learnt that I could also use the EMBED tag.

The default browser for accessing my web app is IE - whatever version. I also supose there should be 
some users using other browsers.

My question is are the drawbacks on each and what have you used before to show video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend using framework which supports HTML5 video tag with flash or other format fallback for old browsers. Examples are [numerous](http://www.google.com/search?q=html5+video+player+with+fallback) and include [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/), [FlareVideo](http://flarevideo.com/) and [others](http://praegnanz.de/html5video/). This way you would depend on (name-your-disadvantages-like-insecure-and-proprietary) technologies only for older browsers and support a newer ones well. The result is fewer problems you face when the management decides to upgrade the clients.

Answer (score 2):

embedding offers the easiest solution. The iframe code is simple and does the job

```
<iframe src="http://(your video source here)" width="400" height="380" frameborder="0">   </iframe>
```